# how to use ifstream to print a char array to a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, save, load

i have a char array saved to a text file and  i have a ifstream system to basically load it i have.

```
        ifstream load;
        load.open("save1.txt");
        for (int f = 0; f < 30; f++)
        {
            load >> map[f];
        }
```

on the load >> map how could i make it print the map in the array like printing on the console like so

```
for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
{
cout << map[i] << endl;
}
```

if i need to be more specific or need more clarification please say so

the expected output would be to print 30 lines but after each line it need to go to the next like endl at the end of load >> map[f] but if there were a endl but there cant be

Comment: Please show us the expected output, or tel us more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put newline characters into the array after each character from the file.

```
for (int f = 0; f < 60; f += 2) {
    load >> map[f];
    map[f+1] = '\n';
}
```

Make sure the array size is at least 60.

Answer (score 0):

`load >> map[i] >> endl;`

Also, in file io, its always a good practice to check if the file is open before continuing.

```
if (load.is_open()){
    // your for loop here with load >> map[i] >> endl
}
```